# No specifications found at path for a valid feature file

Tags: php, behat

I am setting up automated testing with behat (note: I am using behat 3).  I have the following directory structure:

```
project/
    test/
        features/
            web/
                login.feature
            bootstrap/
                Web/
                    LoginContext.php
        behat.yml
```

This is the initial test of the whole approach. I'm explicitly keeping it simple.

My `behat.yml` contains the following (that's all there is in it - everything else will come later).

```
default:
  suites:
    web:
      paths: [%paths.base%/features/web]
      contexts: [Web\LoginContext]
```

My sole feature file contains the following:

```
Feature: Login to MedNav
  In order to use MedNav application
  As a user
  I need to be able to login

  Scenario: Valid login credentials
    Given I am on the login page
     When I enter invalid credentials
      And I hit log in button
     Then I should see "Loading, please wait..."
      And I should navigate to Emergency List page
```

After I executed `behat --init`, it created file `Web\LoginContext`, into which I added the stubs for the steps.

Yet, when I try to execute it, nothing happens:

```
$ bin/behat
No scenarios
No steps
0m0.01s (13.16Mb)
```

If I specify the feature to execute, it tells me that `No specifications found at path(s) 'features/web/login.feature'`

```
$ bin/behat features/web/login.feature 
No scenarios
No steps
0m0.01s (13.16Mb)


  [Behat\Testwork\Tester\Exception\WrongPathsException]             
  No specifications found at path(s) `features/web/login.feature`.  


behat [-s|--suite SUITE] [-f|--format FORMAT] [-o|--out OUT] [--format-settings FORMAT-SETTINGS] [--init] [--lang LANG] [--name NAME] [--tags TAGS] [--role ROLE] [--story-syntax] [-d|--definitions DEFINITIONS] [--append-snippets] [--no-snippets] [--strict] [--order ORDER] [--rerun] [--stop-on-failure] [--dry-run] [--] [<paths>]
```

I've tried moving things around, removing custom directories, suites, etc. - nothing works.

How can I get behat to recognise the feature file?

Comment: comment paths in behat.yml and try again, if that it is not  working then move LoginContext into boostrap and let only LoginContext in the contexts.

Comment: Please add the vendor position, make sure you are executing from the right path.

Comment: @lauda Thanks for the comment.  I rechecked all paths - everything is correct - and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turned out to be much simpler.

Notice this in the `behat.yml`:

```
filters:
    tags: web
```

Because the corresponding context didn't have this tag, the feature didn't execute.  I removed the `tags` for now - and the feature is now run.

Answer (score 0):

Please check again your paths - in your case it should be something similar to:

```
default:
  suites:
    web:
      paths: [ %paths.base%/test/features/web ]
```

And move `behat.yml` file to project root directory. I think calling now `bin/behat` Behat know nothing about `behat.yml` file.

I assume that you are running `bin/behat` from `project/` path.

This is related to: http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/user_guide/configuration.html#custom-autoloading

Comment: I don't execute from the project directory, but from `project/test` - that's my base directory. `behat.yml` sits there and everything else is relative to it  Yet, to be sure, I did exactly what you said - the same result: behat does not find features

Comment: Ok, please remove or comment this line: `paths: [%paths.base%/features/web]` and try to run `bin/behat`.